# Are there any standards/best-practices for managing small non-transactional lookup tables?

Tags: database, database-design, enums, standards

I have an ERP application with about 50 small lookup tables containing non-transactional data. Examples are ItemTypes, SalesOrderStatuses etc. There are so many different types and categories and statuses and with every new module new lookup tables are being added. I have a service to provide List objects out of these tables. These tables usually contain only two columns, (Id and Description). They have only a couple of rows, 8 - 10 rows at max.

I am thinking about putting all of them in one table with ID, Description and LookupTypeID. With this one table I will be able to get rid of 50 tables. Is it good idea? Bad Idea? Very bad idea?

Are there any standards/best-practices for managing small lookup tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among some professionals, the single common lookup table is a design error you should avoid.  At the very least, it will slow down performance.  The reason is that you will have to have a compound primary key for the common table, and lookups via a compound key will take longer than lookups via a simple key.

According to Anith Sen, this is the first of five design errors you should avoid.  See this article: [Five Simple Design Errors](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/)

Answer (score 1):

You can store them in a text search (ie nosql) database like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org). They are ridiculously fast.

I have implemented this to great effect. Note though that there is some initial setup to overcome, but not much. Lucene queries on ids are a snap to write.

Answer (score 1):

Merging lookup tables is a bad idea if you care about integrity of your data (and you should!):

- It would allow "client" tables to reference the data they were not meant to reference. E.g. the DBMS will not protect you from referencing `SalesOrderStatuses` where only `ItemTypes` should be allowed - they are now in the same table and you cannot (easily) separate the corresponding FKs.
- It would force all lookup data to share the same columns and types.

Unless you have a performance problems due to excessive JOINs, I recommend you stay with your current design.

If you do, then you could consider using natural instead of surrogate keys in the lookup tables. This way, the natural keys gets "propagated" through foreign keys to the "client" tables, resulting in less need for JOINing, at the price of increased storage space. For example, instead of having `ItemTypes {Id PK, Description AK}`, only have `ItemTypes {Description PK}`, and you no longer have to JOIN with `ItemTypes` just to get the `Description` - it was automatically propagated down the FK.

Answer (score 1):

The "one big lookup table" approach has the problem of allowing for silly values -- for example "color: yellow" for trucks in the inventory when you only have cars with "color: yellow". One Big Lookup Table: Just Say No.

Off-hand, I would go with the natural keys for the lookup tables unless you would have cases like "the 2012 model CX300R was red but the 2010-2011 models CX300R were blue (and model ID also denotes color)".

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally if you ask a DBA they will say you should have separate tables. If you asked a programmer they would say using the single table is easier. (Makes making a Edit Status webpage very easy you just make one webpage and pass it a different LookupTypeID instead of lots of similar pages)

However now with ORM the SQL and Code to access different status tables is not really any extra effort.

I have used both method and both work fine. I must admit using a single status table is easiest. I have done this for small apps and also enterprise apps and have noticed no performance impacts.

Finally the other field I normally like to add on these generic status tables is a OrderBy field so you can sort the status in your UI by something other than the description if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a good idea to me.  You can have the ID and LookupTypeID as a multi-attribute primary key.  You just need to know what all of the different LookupTypeIDs represent and you should be good as gold.

EDIT:  As for the standards/best-practices, I honestly don't have an answer for you.  I've only had one semester of SQL/database design so I haven't been all too exposed to the matter.